# NullpointerException SQLite Data in ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My next Problem.

I wanna display the data in a listview and i get a Nullpointerexception. My Datasource is a SQLite Database. In the following Text is the Activity and the LogCat.

Please help me!

```
public class ListHaltestelleActivity extends Activity {
private SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    //put the table name and column in constants
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "scotty_haltestelle";
    Intent intent;

.
.
.
.

public void setListView()
{
    try
    {
        myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        // Alle Daten der Datenbank abrufen mithilfe eines Cursors
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select name from scotty_haltestelle",null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        List<Map<String, String>> haltestellenList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            //in this string we get the record for each row from the column "name"
            String name = cursor.getString(0);

            String outPut = name;
            haltestellenList.add(createHaltestelle("haltestelle", outPut));
        }

        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListHaltestelleActivity.this, haltestellenList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[] { "haltestelle" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        //here we close the cursor because we do not longer need it
        //}
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException mSQLException)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}

 // Hash - Map in der die Haltestelle mit Name und dann Number gespeichert wird
    private HashMap<String, String> createHaltestelle(String name, String number) {
        HashMap<String, String> haltestelleNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        haltestelleNameNo.put(name, number);

        return haltestelleNameNo;
```

Here is the logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.atn.android/at.atn.android.ListHaltestelleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at at.atn.android.ListHaltestelleActivity.setListView(ListHaltestelleActivity.java:76)
            at at.atn.android.ListHaltestelleActivity.onCreate(ListHaltestelleActivity.java:61)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
```

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

do

```
db=myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign a value to the `db` member variable, throwing out the result of `myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase()`. This causes the NPE as `db` is not initialized.

Later in the code you will skip the first row as `moveToFirst()` is followed by `moveToNext()`.